# "SSL error parse tlsext" on large commit to SVN via Apache, Gentoo

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, gentoo

This happens only on large commit (resulting in a failed commit):

Revelant section from virtual host config in Apache

```
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
   Dav svn
   SVNPath /home/svn/
```

Commit result:

```
Transmitting file data ..............................svn: Commit failed
(details follow):
svn: PUT of
'/!svn/wrk/48583f7d-0e01-410d-8941-33d2ba3574b4/WAP/.../htdocs/images/rt.gif':
SSL negotiation failed: SSL error: parse tlsext (https://...)
```

I found references to it here: http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=1395

stating that OpenSSL should be compiled with TLS extension, but in my case, it doesn't error out at the start, just on large commits.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: is there an apache httpd bugtracker ticket for this bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't experienced this issue, but I spent a while googling around and found that it may have been introduced in Apache 2.2.12 or 13.  It is suggested that downgrading to 2.2.11 may fix it, as well as setting **SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv2 +SSLv3** in your Apache config.  Neither one seemed definitive.  Good luck!  Hope you find a solution.

http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1065&dsMessageId=2393204

Comment: Adding **SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv2 +SSLv3** worked for me as well.

Comment: For what it is worth, I had the same problem and adding **SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv2 +SSLv3** as mentioned above fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I was having this same problem trying to connect from Ruby 1.9.3. Ruby 1.9.2 wasn't a problem for whatever reason. And the error happened immediately when using a client certificate. Changing my config from `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2` to `SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -TLSv1` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Please note that [SSLv2 has been deprecated since 1996](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/manual/html_node/On-SSL-2-and-older-protocols.html)

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

After reading the http-dev thread about this issue, archived at http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/dev/375633 , it seems this issue is caused by a bug in the client-side OpenSSL library in regards to how SSL Tickets / IDs are handled, which explains why the error does not occur immediately, but takes a few seconds to minutes.  This resolution was determined on Nov 2, three days before OpenSSL 0.9.8l came out.  The thread does not explicitly state if/when the fix was applied to OpenSSL, but I think it's something we can anticipate being fixed in 0.9.8m, which I believe is covered by this entry in the m-beta changelog:

> *) Fixes to stateless session
>   resumption handling. Use initial_ctx
>   when
>        issuing and attempting to decrypt tickets in case it has changed during
>        servername handling. Use a non-zero length session ID when
>   attempting
>        stateless session resumption: this makes it possible to determine if
>        a resumption has occurred immediately after receiving server
>   hello
>        (several places in OpenSSL subtly assume this) instead of later in
>        the handshake.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm experiencing similar issues on Apache-2.2.14 on Gentoo.  For reference, here's my USE flags:

```
[ebuild   R   ] dev-libs/openssl-0.9.8l-r2  USE="zlib -bindist -gmp -kerberos -sse2 -test" 4,082 kB
[ebuild   R   ] www-servers/apache-2.2.14-r1  USE="ssl -debug -doc -ldap (-selinux) -static -suexec -threads" APACHE2_MODULES="actions alias auth_basic auth_digest authn_dbd authn_default authn_file authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_user autoindex dav dav_fs dav_lock dbd deflate dir env expires headers include info log_config logio mime mime_magic negotiation proxy proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_http rewrite setenvif status unique_id userdir -asis -authn_alias -authn_anon -authn_dbm -authz_dbm -authz_owner -cache -cern_meta -charset_lite -disk_cache -dumpio -ext_filter -file_cache -filter* -ident -imagemap -log_forensic -mem_cache -proxy_ajp -proxy_ftp -speling -substitute -usertrack* -version -vhost_alias" APACHE2_MPMS="prefork -event -itk -peruser -worker" 5,088 kB
[ebuild   R   ] net-misc/neon-0.29.0  USE="expat nls ssl zlib -doc -gnutls -kerberos -libproxy -pkcs11" LINGUAS="-cs -de -fr -ja -nn -pl -ru -tr -zh_CN" 859 kB
[ebuild   R   ] dev-util/subversion-1.6.6  USE="apache2 bash-completion dso nls perl python ruby webdav-neon -berkdb -ctypes-python -debug -doc -emacs -extras -gnome-keyring -java -sasl -test -vim-syntax -webdav-serf" 5,384 kB
```

This occurs with any combination of SSLProtocol with `TLSv1` included

If I adjust my `SSLProtocol` to remove `TLSv1`, I get a new error:

```
svn: PUT of '/!svn/wrk/0b9f5a96-15aa-11df-ad6a-0f71b873281b/project/trunk/path/btn_Cancel.gif': SSL handshake failed: SSL error: bad decompression (https://svn.mudbugmedia.com)
```

This occurs at approximately the same time that I'd encounter the "parse tlsext" error instead.

Comment: Upgrading my SVN client from 1.6 to 1.7 solved the "parse tlsext" issue for me, supporting the suggestion by @gabe-martin-dempesy that "this issue is caused by a bug in the client-side OpenSSL library"

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most propably because of using multiple SSL enabled VirtualHosts in Apache httpd 2.2.12 - 2.2.14 and OpenSSL 0.9.8f - 0.9.8l .

The following [patch](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/200911.mbox/%3C4AF58A80.5080101@velox.ch%3E) seems to solve the issue for me.