# Upgrade openssl/mod_ssl on Mac OS X Server?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx-server, openssl, mod-ssl

Context: I'm trying to set up an SVN server on a Mac OS X Server 10.6.7, and I'm running into the [“SSL error parse tlsext”](https://serverfault.com/questions/44470/ssl-error-parse-tlsext-on-large-commit-to-svn-via-apache-gentoo) issue. I've tried changing the `SSLProtocol` option as described, but then I just get the ["bad decompression"](https://serverfault.com/questions/44470/ssl-error-parse-tlsext-on-large-commit-to-svn-via-apache-gentoo/111252#111252) error.

The other solution seems to be to upgrade openssl to 0.9.8m or greater.

I can download and compile openssl just fine, but I don't know the best way to hook it into the default installation of Apache and mod_ssl. I'd like to stick with the built-in Apple software as much as possible, and preferably not overwrite their version of openssl either.

How do I update mod_ssl to use a new version of openssl on Mac OS X Server 10.6?

Comment: You'll have to recompile mod_ssl with the newer OpenSSL you want to use.

http://www.modssl.org/example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CocoaBean has pointed out you will need to rebuild mod_ssl linking against the OpenSSL library you want to use rather than the one that comes with OS X.  You would want to grab a copy of the [Apache source code, as used in OS X](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/unix_open_source/apache.html) (or the latest from [httpd.apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/)) and then rebuild it in accordance with the [Apache Foundation's installation instructions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html), paying special attention to how you specify which SSL library you want to link against.

Ideally you should only need to rebuild `mod_ssl.so`, but my suggestion would be to build and install a separate Apache instance to avoid any problems during OS X updates that could result in your modifications getting blown away.